# Scrapy write to multiple MongoDB collections

Tags: mongodb, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, pymongo

I am trying to store separate items in separate mongodb collections with pymongo and scrapy.

How should I approach a creating a pipeline that 
1) starts a dictionary of pymongo connections when the spider opens, 
2) processes and identifies an item by name, 
3) and inserts the item to one of the collections within a given request.

I am not sure if it even possible write to multiple collections in scrapy. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure about your question, do you want to store same data into 2 databases?

Comment: Solved it! Thanks Umair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was initially trying to make a dict object of collections in which a spider could write different items to.

After some research I came across 'connection pooling' in mongodb docs, and realized I needed to make the dict object of connections to multiple endpoints rather than multiple collections using 1 connection.

```
class MongoDBPipeline(BaseItemExporter):

 #...

    #item types for mongo to insert to correct collection
     writeTypes = [
        'ent_pfrm', 'ent_prsn', 
        'ent_sctn', 'ent_meet', 
        'ent_venu', 'ent_affn'
     ]

 #...

    def open_spider(self, spider):

        #Set db dict
        self.database = dict([(name,connection[self.config['database']][name]) for name in self.writeTypes])
```

Once an item is processed, get the name, check the dict, and insert if there is a match

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    def item_type(item):
        return type(item).__name__.replace('_Item','').lower()  # Team_Item => team

    item_name = item_type(item)

    #check if the item matches one of the 'writeTypes'
    if item_name in self.database.keys(): 
        dbcol = self.database[item_name]
        dbcol.insert(item)

    return item
```